# Parsing Json to Data frame in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I have json data in the following format.

```
{"abc": "37512", "def": "93145", "ghi": "14160", "jkl": "510842"}
```

I need to load it in R session as data frame.

```
col1 col2
abc 37512
def 93145
ghi 14160
jkl 510842
```

I tried to parse the json using rsjon. Here is my code:

```
library("rjson")

json_file <- 'finaldata.json'
data <- fromJSON(file=json_file)
data
$abc
[1] "37512"

$def
[1] "93145"

$ghi
[1] "14160"

$jkl
[1] "510842"
```

This gives me the output as list. How can I get the desired output as data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` from `base R`

```
 stack(data)
 #  values ind
 #1  37512 abc
 #2  93145 def
 #3  14160 ghi
 #4 510842 jkl
```

or  `melt` from `reshape2`

```
 library(reshape2)
 melt(data)
```

and change the column names

```
 setNames(melt(data)[,2:1], paste0('col', 1:2))
 #  col1   col2
 #1  abc  37512
 #2  def  93145
 #3  ghi  14160
 #4  jkl 510842
```